# Saving Result in different vector in R

Tags: r

The following are the URLs I wish to extract:

```
 > links
 [1] "https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/"                 
 [2] "https://www.makemytrip.com/holidays-india/"                 
 [3] "https://www.yatra.com/india-tour-packages"                   
 [4] "http://www.thomascook.in/tcportal/international-holidays"   
 [5] "https://www.yatra.com/holidays"                             
 [6] "https://www.travelguru.com/holiday-packages/domestic-packages.shtml"
 [7] "https://www.chanbrothers.com/package"                       
 [8] "https://www.tourmyindia.com/packagetours.html"               
 [9] "http://traveltriangle.com/tour-packages"                     
[10] "http://www.coxandkings.com/bharatdeko/"                     
[11] "https://www.sotc.in/india-tour-packages"
```

I have managed to do it using:

```
for (i in 1:10){ 
 html <- getURL(links[i], followlocation = TRUE)

 parse html
 doc = htmlParse(html, asText=TRUE)
 plain.text <- xpathSApply(doc, "//text()[not(ancestor::script)][not(ancestor::style)][not(ancestor::noscript)][not(ancestor::form)]", xmlValue)}
```

But the thing is all extracted data are all saved in "plain.text." How do I have "plain.text" for each link?

Thank you.

Comment: can you make the plain.text as a list? Then append data for each loop iteration in the list.

Comment: Do you want to save each HTML page locally? By what names? Or you want to store them all in the memory and then do something with html in the R? Please explain what you want to get in the end.

Comment: My objective is to extract the keywords of these URLs. Then calculate its TF, IDF, TF-IDF of the terms.